# Speeding up constrained optimization problem solving

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem on my homework with Lagrangian multipliers that Mathematica has now been bashing at fruitlessly for 10 minutes. I'm not sure whether I did something horribly wrong codewise, but it's definitely a big ugly function that it is trying to optimize with constraints.

Here's the problem: I need to maximize `f` with regards to `c` and `n` if `v` is held constant at `20000`.

```
p = 15 n (10 - c) - c^2;
v = 0.5 p + n*Sqrt[p];
f = c*p - v;
```

As you can probably tell, `f`, when properly expanded, is huge. Its derivatives are even uglier, making maximization absolutely nasty. I tried having Mathematica solve Lagrangian Multipliers on its own, so that with values of c and n I could just plug in to see what f's max was:

```
g1 = D[v, c]
g2 = D[v, n]
f1 = D[f, c]
f2 = D[f, n]
Solve[f1 == lam*g1 && f2 == lam*g2 && v == 20000, {c, n}]
```

It's been sitting for 25 minutes. 5 minutes later, I ssh'd to another machine and started this:

```
Maximize[{f, v == 20000}, {c, n}]
```

And that one has been going for 15 now. Is there something I can do to make this go faster? I'm running on a machine with 4 cores, 8 gigs of ram and an i7, it should be able to handle this. I have a lot of problems like this, and don't have time to let it go overnight :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: I forgot to mention that first I changed the coefficients to exact numbers:

```
p = 15 n (10 - c) - c^2;
v = (1/2) p + n*Sqrt[p];
f = c*p - v;
```

Then I did what I posted originally:

The following returns an answer in less than 0.1 sec.:

```
Solve[f1 == lam*g1 && f2 == lam*g2 && v == 20000, {c, n, lam}, Method -> Reduce]
```

If I add `lam` to `Maximize`, I get this disappointing result:

```
Maximize[{f, v == 20000}, {c, n, lam}]
```

> Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.  >>

```
{∞, {c -> Indeterminate, n -> Indeterminate, lam -> Indeterminate}}
```

Comment: Huh. Looks like I forgot to solve for lam, but what does Method->Reduce do?

Comment: `ClearAll[p, f, v, lam, g1, g2, f1, f2, c, n, "Global*\`"]
p = 15 n (10 - c) - c^2;
v = 0.5 p + n*Sqrt[p];
f = c*p - v;
g1 = D[v, c]
g2 = D[v, n]
f1 = D[f, c]
f2 = D[f, n]
Solve[f1 == lam*g1 && f2 == lam*g2 && v == 20000, {c, n, lam}, 
 Method -> Reduce]`
This is my exact, complete code now, it's still just sitting there chillin' again. What could be up? @michael-e2

Comment: @laudiacay Try it now.  I forgot something. -- `Method -> Reduce` is in the docs.  It makes `Solve` use `Reduce` to reduce the system.  `Reduce` is more picky and produces a system equivalent to the given one; `Solve` by default looks for solutions that are generically valid. Often it takes longer and produces more complete results.  Here "picky" turns out to be faster.

Comment: Wow, you learn something new every day. Thank god I only have to find real numerical solutions for now.